# Given a collection of cuboids, How to find another collection that cover the first collection 2 times the volume

Tags: general-topology

Assume we have a countable collection of cuboids $  \left\{ J_{i}\right\} _{i\in I} $

each cuboid is an n-dimenional cubould $ J_i\subset \mathbb{R}^n $

Such that $ \sum_{i\in I}\text{vol}\left(J_{i}\right)<\varepsilon $

Is it possible to manipulate each cuboid and get a new collection $ \{\tilde{J}_{i}\}_{i\in I} $ such that each new cuboid  $ \tilde{J}_{i} $ would satisfy:

$ J_{i}\subset\text{int}\left(\tilde{J}_{i}\right) $ and also

$ \sum_{i\in I}\text{vol}\left(\tilde{J}_{i}\right)<2\varepsilon $?

Im pretty sure that its possible but I cant see how to formally prove it, my intuition is that I want to make each one-dimesional segment a little bit bigger, such that the new volume would only increase by $ \frac{1}{2^{n}}\varepsilon $, so that $ \text{ vol}\left(\tilde{J}_{i}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{2^{n}\varepsilon }+\text{vol}J_{i}\right) $  and then since the index set $ I $ is countable, I can assume that the cardinality is $ \aleph_0 $ and the write:

$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\text{vol}\tilde{J}_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}vol\left(J_{i}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2^{n}}\varepsilon\right)<\varepsilon+\varepsilon=2\varepsilon $

But I could not find out how to do it precisly. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does $n$ depends on $i$? If yes, why not writing $J_i \subseteq \mathbb R^i$? If not, making the same homothetic ratio for all cuboids will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = 2^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$. Replace $J_i$ with a cuboid whose center is the same, but where each edge's length is multiplied by $u > 1$. Then you have a cuboid containing $J'_i$ containing $J_i$, and the volume of $J'_i$ is
$$
v' = u^n v
$$
where $v$ is the volume of $J_i$. But $u^n = 2^\frac{n}{n+1} < 2^1 = 2$, so $v' < 2v.$

Comment: How do you define the center of the cuboid? since its non symmetric I cant understand the intuition

Comment: I suppose that I thought a cuboid was a product of intervals, one on each axis (i.e., an axis-aligned cuboid), like $[1, 3] \times [2, 5]$. In such a case, the "center" is just $(2, 3.5)$, i.e., the sequence of all interval-centers. Even if they're not axis-aligned, if it's a cuboid, there's some coordinate system in which they ARE axis-aligned, and my approach still works. But maybe your notion of "cuboid" and mine differ.